# Error compiling sass on mytheme

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vaadin

Every time when I try to use my my theme on Visual Studio Code it gives me this error:

`"Error compiling sass". 
File "c:\applic\studentDemo\src\main\VAADIN\themes\mytheme" not found(32/10)`

It was working normally before, I got to do many things using myTheme, but I have no idea what i have done there. Somebody help me, please .

Thank you.

Comment: should it not be named `mytheme.scss` ?

Answer (score 0):

`\VAADIN` should not be under `src\main` directly. The path should be `src\main\webapp\VAADIN\...` (or in Eclipse, possibly under `WebContent\`...)

[See documentation about using and creating themes](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/themes/themes-creating.html)

Comment: File "c:\applic\studentDemo\src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes\mytheme" not found.

Comment: Could you share the contents of the mytheme folder? How did you create the project (which Maven archetype, if any)?

Comment: yes sure. So, every time when i go to myTheme.scss and try to do something i get an error.

Answer (score 0):

yes sure. So, every time when i go to myTheme.scss and try to do something i get the error.

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss; 
@mixin mytheme{ 
@include valo;


}
```

Comment: I created an maven project (maven:generate from archetype)with vaadin(vaadin-archetype-application).